# What's "All Transactions" in IOTA Peer Manager?

Tags: iri-node

All transactions does not seem to be the sum of the rest of transactions. What is it then?

See screenshot:

[image: IOTA Peer Manager]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All Transactions** denote all incoming transactions from a particular neighbor.

**New Transactions** is a subset of All Transactions and count the tx your node has not seen yet.

**Sent Transactions** is the sum of all New Transactions from all neighbors minus the new tx it received from the node it is sending to. Your node broadcasts all new tx it received to all other nodes.

Comment: Can you also define the other two: Random Transactions and Invalid Transactions?