# Interpretation of getNeigbors cmd output

Tags: iri-node

I am trying to understand the different numbers this command outputs and how they relate. Can anyone shed some more light on this? E.g.

```
"neighbors": [
    {
      "address": "xxxxxxxxx:14600",
      "numberOfAllTransactions": 252391,
      "numberOfRandomTransactionRequests": 19152,
      "numberOfNewTransactions": 21744,
      "numberOfInvalidTransactions": 0,
      "numberOfSentTransactions": 242167,
      "connectionType": "udp"
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `address`

**IP address:port** or **domain name:port** of neighbor

## `numberOfAllTransactions`

Number of **all** transactions the neighbor sent to you. **Invalid**, **valid** and **already-seen**.
[is incremented here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/3aebf94425509798d046ac5b47302817ab65bb4d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L234)

## `numberOfRandomTransactionRequest`

Number of random tips the neighbor requested from your node.
[is incremented here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/3aebf94425509798d046ac5b47302817ab65bb4d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L409)

## `numberOfNewTransactions`

Number of new transactions received from the neighbor. New transactions are transactions that you have not yet stored when the neighbor sends it to you.
[is incremented here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/3aebf94425509798d046ac5b47302817ab65bb4d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L393)

## `numberOfInvalidTransactions`

Number of invalid transactions the neighbor sent you.
is incremented [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/3aebf94425509798d046ac5b47302817ab65bb4d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L271) and [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/3aebf94425509798d046ac5b47302817ab65bb4d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L380)

## `numberOfSentTransactions`

Number of all new transactions you get from other neighbors and forward to that neighbor.
(You forward *all new transactions* from one neighbor to all other neighbours)
So the number is exactly the sum of all new transactions from your neighbors except this neighbor.
[is incremented here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/30497513e538f5568c9f3593f22884e1c3236a8b/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/replicator/ReplicatorSinkProcessor.java#L101)

## `connection`

Wether your nodes are sending each other transactions via UDP or TCP

Comment: Nice thanks. I do think however that numberOfSentTransactions has to be adjusted a bit. Copy/pasting from this [answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/864/whats-all-transactions-in-iota-peer-manager): Sent Transactions is the sum of all New Transactions from all neighbors minus the new tx it received from the node it is sending to. Your node broadcasts all new tx it received to all other nodes.

Comment: Yes, thats just a complicated way of saying "number of transactions you sent to your neighbor" isn't it? I edited the answer to make it more understandable.

Comment: true but it also gives a bit more background in how the set of tx to send is determined

Answer (score 2):

You are probably asking for the meaning of different transactions terms. You can find a quite good answer in [What's “All Transactions” in IOTA Peer Manager?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/864/whats-all-transactions-in-iota-peer-manager).

You can also look at file [Node.java](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/03ac9c4897c9716a0ad1400a48fb5f341df1e2b2/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java) of IRI code searching for occurences of `neighbor.incAllTransactions();`, `neighbor.incNewTransactions();`, `neighbor.incRandomTransactionRequests();`,  `neighbor.incInvalidTransactions();`. The `inc` prefix stands for increment.